# How to Type My Own Node Module Using a .d.ts File

Tags: typescript, webpack

I am bundling my node module using webpack and awesome-typescript-loader. I am importing the bundled module into another package. Within the other package I get the error:

`Could not find a declaration file for module 'mymodule'`

My default export for the package is an initialized class:

```
import MyClass from './myClass';
const c = new MyClass();
export default c;
```

and from my package I import:

```
import c from 'mymodule';
```

MyClass is typed within its file, but how can I export a .d.ts file from the module, so my other package knows about the MyClass types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `types.d.ts` file in your lib folder, and add the `types: "./types.d.ts"` property to its `package.json`.

This will allow to TS access to all the types that your lib is exporting.

But, you will need to write those types by hand.

A better solution, is to let TS generate those `d.ts` files for you.
You can achieve that by enabling `declaration: true` in your `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: Perfect thanks. I had tried that, but it didn't work. I realized that I had webpack output a file called bundle.js - while the main export was typed in main.d.ts. After I renamed bundle to main and updated the "main" property in my package.json file it seems to work now.